# Footnote within a double column float

Tags: footnotes, multicol, mdframed

I have a double-column float that is used to insert a full-page box in a document. However, when I place footnotes in this box, the footnotes appear within the box (which is desired) but not in a twocolumn geometry (undesired).

The current output is in the first box in the MWE below. I've developed a kludge to obtain the desired result (second box). Is there a better solution?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[twocolumn,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{multicol}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={List of boxes}, name = {Box}]{boxe}

\mdfdefinestyle{GrattanFrameBox}{%
    nobreak=true, % prevents page breaking
    outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=11pt,
    innerleftmargin=11pt
    }

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{bigbox*}[2]{%
  \setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
  \@dblfloat{boxe}%
  \begin{mdframed}[style=GrattanFrameBox]
  \setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}
   \captionsetup{labelfont={bf}, font={bf}, format=plain,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
  \caption{#1}\label{#2}
%   \vspace*{-4.125ex}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value
%
 \vspace{-1.5ex}
}{%
  \end{multicols}\end{mdframed}
  \end@dblfloat
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \lipsum
 \begin{bigbox*}{Title}{box:Title}
 \lipsum*[1-2]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

 \lipsum[3]
 \end{bigbox*}
 \lipsum
 \begin{bigbox*}{Title2}{box:Title2}
 \lipsum*[1-2]\footnote{\vspace{-30pt}\begin{multicols}{2}
                        \lipsum[1] 
                        \end{multicols}
                        }

 \lipsum[3]
 \end{bigbox*}


\end{document}
```

[image: Current big box outcome]

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: multicol doc, in the abstract: `Footnotes are handled correctly
(for the most part), but will be placed at the bottom of the page and not under each column`

Comment: No, it's still unanswered. The kludge is my current work-around.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you found a good workaround. Because of the limitation through package `multicol` I think that is a very good solution.

I only would define a new command like `\footnotebigbox`

```
\newcommand{\footnotebigbox}[1]{\footnote{\vspace{-30pt}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}#1\end{multicols}
}}
```

for less writing.  Then you can use it with `\footnotebigbox{text of footnote}` in your `bigbox` environment.

See box 3 in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[twocolumn,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{multicol}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={List of boxes}, name = {Box}]{boxe}



\mdfdefinestyle{GrattanFrameBox}{%
  nobreak=true, % prevents page breaking
  outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
  innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,
  innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
  innerrightmargin=11pt,
  innerleftmargin=11pt
}

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{bigbox*}[2]{%
  \setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
  \@dblfloat{boxe}%
  \begin{mdframed}[style=GrattanFrameBox]
  \setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}
   \captionsetup{labelfont={bf}, font={bf}, format=plain,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
  \caption{#1}\label{#2}
%   \vspace*{-4.125ex}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value
%
 \vspace{-1.5ex}
}{%
  \end{multicols}\end{mdframed}
  \end@dblfloat
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\footnotebigbox}[1]{\footnote{\vspace{-30pt}% <=============
  \begin{multicols}{2}#1\end{multicols}
}}


\begin{document}

\lipsum
\begin{bigbox*}{Title}{box:Title}
  \lipsum*[1-2]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

  \lipsum[3]
\end{bigbox*}
\lipsum
\begin{bigbox*}{Title2}{box:Title2}
  \lipsum*[1-2]\footnote{\vspace{-30pt}\begin{multicols}{2}
                         \lipsum[1] 
                         \end{multicols}
                         }

  \lipsum[3]
\end{bigbox*}

\lipsum
\begin{bigbox*}{Title3}{box:Title3}% <==================================
  \lipsum*[1-2]\footnotebigbox{\lipsum[1]}% 

  \lipsum[3]
\end{bigbox*}
\end{document}
```

with the wanted result:

[image: box 3 of mwe above]